# Angular filter with autocomplete undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to get some result from a custom filter with a input and a dropdwon i made. Typing in the input should be start the filter and should show the filtered results. This is the function:

```
$scope.filterText = "";
$scope.filterDropdown = function(textTyped) {
    var searchFilter = $scope.baseUrl + "&searchStr=";


    return $http.get(searchFilter + textTyped, {
        cache: true
    }).then(function(data) {
        $scope.results = data.data.data.data;

        return $scope.results;
    });
};
```

and here the html:

```
 <input type="text" data-ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0} }"
       ng-model="item.search_value" placeholder="{{item.description}}" data-ng-change="filterDropdown(filterText)"/>
<div>
    <ul data-ng-repeat="descriptions in results.description">
        <li>{{descriptions}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

actually i can see only a list of the entire json! I mean, when i start type the function starts but the text i type not works and the result is something like:

```
http://192.168.1.121:8280/test/searchStr=
```

where the searchStr should be fill every time i type a word. For example, i want to search : hello. I will press "h"

```
http://192.168.1.121:8280/test/searchStr=h
```

then

```
http://192.168.1.121:8280/test/searchStr=he
http://192.168.1.121:8280/test/searchStr=hel
http://192.168.1.121:8280/test/searchStr=hell
http://192.168.1.121:8280/test/searchStr=hello
```

understand? How can i fix?

Comment: input model is bound to "ng-model="item.search_value"" and ng-change is bound to some other scope variable "filterText". ng-change should be bound to ng-model variable (item.search_value) if change in the input text should be passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass ng-model name in calling function.

```
data-ng-change="filterDropdown(item.search_value)

<input type="text" 
data-ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0} }"
ng-model="item.search_value" placeholder="{{item.description}}" data-ng-change="filterDropdown(item.search_value)"/>
```